# concept extraction using Wordnet

Tags: nlp, semantics, text-mining, wordnet

I wish to know how can i used WordNet to extract concepts from a text document.Earlier I have used bag of words approach to measure similarity between text documents, however i wish to use semantic information of text therefore wants to extract concepts from the document.I understand Wordnet offer Sysnet that contains synonyms for the given word.
 however what i am trying to achieve is that how can i use this information to define a concept in the textual data. I wonder should i need to define the list of concepts separately and manually before using sysnet and than compare those concepts with the sysnet.

Any suggestion or link is appreciated.

Comment: I don't unerstand, are you trying to do "keyword extraction"? What do you mean by concept? Sorry if my question sound silly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that there are too many concepts out there for enumerating all of them yourself to be practical. Instead, you should consider using a pre-existing source of knowledge such as [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page), [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/), [Freebase](https://www.freebase.com/), the content of Tweets, the web at large, or some other source as the basis for constructing your concepts. You may find clustering algorithms useful for defining these. In terms of synonyms... words related to a concept may not necessarily be synonymous (e.g. both love and hate may be connected to the same concept regarding an intensity of emotion towards someone else) and some words could belong to multiple concepts (e.g. wedding could be in both the love and in the marriage concept), so I'd suggest having some linkage from synset to concept that isn't strictly 1:1.